# "Store map" auf Deutsch

Tags: single-word-request

Verzweifelt gesucht wird ein deutscher Begriff, der die Karte eines Geschäfts bezeichnet (Lage der Regale, Kassen etc.)

> Geschäftsplan
>
> Filialplan
>
> Geschäftskarte
>
> Filialkarte
>
> Übersicht

Alles klingt uneindeutig, unverständlich oder irgendwie falsch.

Comment: Ladengrundriss?

Comment: Muss es unbedingt ein einzelnes Wort sein? Ich würde spontan an etwas wie "Überblick über die Filiale" oder "Die Filiale im Überblick" denken. Eine andere Möglichkeit wäre das gerne genommene "Was finde ich wo?", aber das wäre komplett weg von "store map".

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck kannst du es bitte als Antwort posten? Ich weiß zwar noch nicht, ob es DIE Lösung ist, aber es sind auf jeden Fall sehr gute Ansätze!

Comment: Ich würde nichts mit "Plan" am Ende benutzen. Klingt zu sher nach planen. Geschäftsplan wäre für mich eine Beschreibung, wie man ein Geschäft führen will, mit der man bei Kreditgebern vorstellig wird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wenn es nicht unbedingt ein einzelnes Wort sein muss, würde ich Ausdrücke aus mehreren Wörtern in die Überlegung einbeziehen. Da gibt es viel mehr Gestaltungsmöglichkeiten. Mir würde beispielsweise etwas in Richtung "Überblick über die Filiale", "Die Filiale im Überblick" einfallen. Wenn zusätzlich noch der direkte Rückbezug auf "store map" wegfallen kann, wären auch das gerne genommene "Was finde ich wo?" oder etwas wie "Ihr Wegweiser durch " überlegenswert.

Comment: Am Ende waren deine Vorschläge tatsächlich am passendsten. Du hast den Sinn und Zweck als eine Überschrift in einer Software vollständig erkannt und sehr gute Ideen gebracht. Wir haben uns für "Was finde ich wo?" entschieden. Es ergab sich eine interessante Diskussion über den Unterschied zwischen "Was finde ich wo" und "Wo finde ich was" :) Schade allerdings, dass man "Store map" doch nicht wörtlich übersetzen kann.

Comment: @BarthZalewski Naja, eigentlich ist doch "Ladenplan" ganz quadratisch-praktisch-gut. Und auch ein eingeführter Begriff (Google das mal).

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous ist nicht schlecht, aber klingt nicht so peppig. Lustigerweise finde ich auch "Bin Ladens Plan" unter diesem Begriff ^^ Und bisher hat auch niemand diesen Begriff vorgeschlagen.

Comment: Dass niemand das naheliegendste und eindeutige Wort Ladenplan vorgeschlagen hat, fand ich tatsächlich recht verwunderlich, und ich wollte deswegen schon eine Antwort schreiben.

Answer (score 4):

Ich finde die "Grundriss"-Zusammensetzungen nicht so treffend, weil sie m. E. auch nur die Mauern meinen könnten.

Meine Vorschlag ist auch nicht perfekt, weil

> Lageplan

auch die Lage des Ladens im Stadtviertel bezeichnen könnte, aber eben auch die Lage seiner Einrichtung im Laden; das wird der Kontext aber schon richten, über das entsprechende Diagramm kann man *Lageplan* sehr gut schreiben.

Answer (score 1):

> Geschäftsgrundriss

Wäre meine erste Wahl, da eindeutig und nicht zu verwechseln. Laden, Geschäft und Filiale lassen sich da beliebig austauschen, je nach dem was für ein Geschäft es ist.

> Geschäftsgrundplan

Ginge auch noch. Wobei ich Grundplan als nicht so geläuftig wie Grundriss betrachten würde.